# Temperature of the sunset/sunrise band of a tidally locked planet

Tags: science-based, planets, tides

Assuming an Earth-like planet (in terms of size, distance from sun etc) that is tidally locked to its sun, it would seem that the "dayside" would be permenantly burning and the "nightside" permenantly frozen. However, would the band which is constantly experiencing a sunrise/sunset be a habitable temperature, and if so is there a way to determine how wide this habitable band would be?

Comment: Nothing bad happened. Closed as duplicate is no punishment. Glad you got your answers. It's just that some of us have been here a bit longer, and we've seen questions asked earlier. You couldn't remember someone called this band a twilight zone, and we know it. Also, as far as I remember, occasional duplicates are not counted when calculating question ban (other close reasons, downvotes and deleted question are counted), so leaving it will help others to find what they need and won't hurt you in any way.

Comment: Psychro - A tidally locked planet orbiting an Earth like distance from its star is not very probable.  People think about tidally locked planets because planets in the habitable zone of dim red dwarf stars - the most common stars - will be tidally locked because they will have to be very close to their dim stars to be inside the habitable zone, and so they will be close enough to become tidally locked.  But a planet orbiting its star at about Earth's distance from the Sun will not be tidally locked unless it is a super massive star and the planet will be too hot anyway..